# Xamarin Android Profiler won't start — "Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

We're struggling to get the Xamarin Profiler to start with our Android application.

We're using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.4.3) with Xamarin Profiler v1.6.0.16, Xamarin version 4.7.10.38.

Every time we try to use the profiler, it simply stops and writes to its log file:

> Runtime installed on device [...] is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio.

This confuses us since we're not using Xamarin Studio at all.

We've tried:

- checking for VS/Xamarin updates (obviously).
- creating a new empty Xamarin project and attempting to profile it.
- various devices and emulators.
- various combinations of 'Target Framework', 'Minimum Android version' and 'Target Android version'.
- Windows 7 and Windows 10.
- Visual Studio both v15.4.3 and v15.5.0.
- 'Enable developer instrumentation (debugging and profiling)' is checked.
- 'Use Shared Runtime' and 'Use Fast Deployment' checked/unchecked.

But we always get the same result: "Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio".

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated; thanks.

The profiler's log file is as follows:

```
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.2416] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.2416] # Xamarin Profiler version -  1.6.0.16
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.2416] #  * Arch x86_64
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.2416] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.3820] initializing android platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.3820] initializing ios platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.3820] initializing mlpd platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:34.4600] processing command line = C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin\Profiler\XamarinProfiler.exe --type=android --target=au.com.<redacted>|md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen --device=025b38394ca8478b --options=name:LGE Nexus 5X
XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:44.6840] Creating android run for au.com.<redacted>|md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen target on device 025b38394ca8478b
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:44.7152] Initializing profiling...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:44.7620] Waiting for device 025b38394ca8478b to connect
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:44.7620] StartRecording for au.com.<redacted>
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:45.4582] checking runtime version on device LGE Nexus 5X
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1802] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1802] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1812] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1822] Stopping application au.com.<redacted>.md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1892] Error occured on run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.1892] Error occured on run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.2812] Application au.com.<redacted>.md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.2852] Stopping session. Please wait...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.2952] Stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:19:46.2982] CurrentRun.Finished for au.com.<redacted>
XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:48.4232] Creating android run for au.com.<redacted>|md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen target on device 025b38394ca8478b
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:48.4232] Initializing profiling...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:48.4562] Waiting for device 025b38394ca8478b to connect
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:48.4562] StartRecording for au.com.<redacted>
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.0302] checking runtime version on device LGE Nexus 5X
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7792] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7792] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7792] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7792] Stopping application au.com.<redacted>.md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7802] Error occured on run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.7802] Error occured on run au.com.<redacted>: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.8902] Application au.com.<redacted>.md52635741fd041340e6948a5329c9048f1.MainScreen stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.8902] Stopping session. Please wait...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.8902] Stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-11-15 10:20:50.8912] CurrentRun.Finished for au.com.<redacted>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you are all downloading the profiler from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/tools/profiler/?tabs=windows

which actually is a link to an older version with a bug, try downloading it from 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/tools/profiler/release-notes/1.6/1.6.4

with the latest stable version and it should work, at least it did for me.
[image]
cheers

Comment: Maybe it would be better to provide a link that always give the latest version, instead of the latest version only as of now(April 2019)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/tools/profiler/release-notes/

Answer (score 0):

Same here, adding research. Xamarin Profiler fails with the example SingleViewApp Xamarin project running on LGE Nexus 5X Android 8.0.0 but succeeds running on old Samsung SM-T280 Android 5.1.1.

Failure case profiler log

```
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.5188] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.5207] # Xamarin Profiler version -  1.6.0.16
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.5207] #  * Arch x86_64
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.5207] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.7168] initializing android platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.7168] initializing ios platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.7174] initializing mlpd platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:34.8973] processing command line = C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin\Profiler\XamarinProfiler.exe --type=android --target=SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp|singleviewapp.SingleViewApp --device=00d0eee43fcc3e58 --options=name:LGE Nexus 5X
XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:45.4078] Creating android run for SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp|singleviewapp.SingleViewApp target on device 00d0eee43fcc3e58
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:45.4293] Initializing profiling...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:45.4850] Waiting for device 00d0eee43fcc3e58 to connect
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:45.4880] StartRecording for SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:48.0039] checking runtime version on device LGE Nexus 5X
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5410] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Error: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5410] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5420] Sorry, something went wrong trying to run SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5430] Stopping application SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp.singleviewapp.SingleViewApp
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5470] Error occured on run SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Error: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.5470] Error occured on run SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp: Runtime installed on device LGE Nexus 5X is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.7319] Application SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp.singleviewapp.SingleViewApp stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.7470] Stopping session. Please wait...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.7571] Stopped
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:47:49.7754] CurrentRun.Finished for SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp
```

Failure case Android logcat

```
12-03 14:37:34.523: D/AndroidRuntime(19727): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
12-03 14:37:34.781: D/AndroidRuntime(19727): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
12-03 14:37:34.813: I/app_process(19727): System.exit called, status: 0
12-03 14:37:34.813: I/AndroidRuntime(19727): VM exiting with result code 0.
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727): Handler (android.os.Handler) {6ee8755} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (android.os.Handler) {6ee8755} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:545)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:661)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:630)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:600)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:356)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.send(ResultReceiver.java:57)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at com.android.internal.os.IResultReceiver$Stub.onTransact(IResultReceiver.java:58)
12-03 14:37:34.815: W/MessageQueue(19727):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:674)
12-03 14:37:35.793: I/ActivityManager(771): Force stopping SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp appid=10444 user=0: from pid 19740
```

Success case profiler log

```
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.2196] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.2216] # Xamarin Profiler version -  1.6.0.16
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.2226] #  * Arch x86_64
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.2226] ##########################################
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.4174] initializing android platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.4174] initializing ios platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.4186] initializing mlpd platform
XamarinProfiler.Core.Profiler Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:56:40.8207] processing command line = C:\Program Files (x86)\Xamarin\Profiler\XamarinProfiler.exe --type=android --target=SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp|singleviewapp.SingleViewApp --device=3100784abd71b200 --options=name:Samsung SM-T280
XamarinProfiler.Windows.Core.WindowsRunFactory Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:15.4411] Creating android run for SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp|singleviewapp.SingleViewApp target on device 3100784abd71b200
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:15.4632] Initializing profiling...
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:15.5209] Waiting for device 3100784abd71b200 to connect
XamarinProfiler.Windows.MainWindow Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:15.5229] StartRecording for SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Android.ProfileAndroidRun Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:17.6114] checking runtime version on device Samsung SM-T280
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:19.0527] Starting application SingleViewApp.SingleViewApp.singleviewapp.SingleViewApp
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:20.8807] Starting profiler on Android device Samsung SM-T280 with heapshot=ondemand,alloc,nocalls,maxframes=8,counters,
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:21.6067] Opening C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\hlvkcpc1.mlpd
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Mono.MlpdReader Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:21.6323] opening C:\Users\robert\AppData\Local\Temp\hlvkcpc1.mlpd
XamarinProfiler.Core.Platforms.Mono.MlpdReader Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:21.9964] read header with format version 13
XamarinProfiler.Windows.ViewModels.ProgressReport.ReportViewModel Information: 0 : [2017-12-03 14:57:22.5255] Reading data...
```

Success case Android logcat (too long to include)

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Visual Studio to Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (**15.6.2**) and the Profiler will work. I had the same proble